# Calling a stateful widget from another stateful widget does not work as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

Calling a statefulwidget from a button click of another widget does not do anything. What I am trying to do is execute a print statement just to see if the calling works

I have this ElevatedButton below which calls the Stateful Widget Contacts, I dont see any errors but I dont see the print statement printed out in the console.

```
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        const Contacts(name: 'Jimmy');
      },
      child: const Text('Fetch API data'),
    ),

class Contacts extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  const Contacts({Key? key, required this.name}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ContactsState createState() => _ContactsState();
}

class _ContactsState extends State<Contacts> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Test2');
    return Center(child: Text(widget.name));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`State` objects will not be created unless added to the widget tree.

Comment: Am I not adding it to the widget tree inside of the elevated button.

Comment: No you're just creating a new instance of `Contacts` and then discarding it completely.

Comment: How do I make this work, an example code would be great. I want to make Contacts widgets a reusable widget.

Comment: Currently the `Contacts` widget is totally reusable you just need to return it in some other widgets build method. So that it gets added to the widget tree.

Comment: Can you show an example on my code above

Comment: For example wherever you've placed that `ElevatedButton` you can just replace it with `Contacts` and it will work.

Comment: But I want the widgets to pop up only when the button is pressed

Comment: Just like a popup?

Comment: The Contacts widget will have a bottom sheet widget with all the contacts listed that's what the plan is.

Comment: Then you should call `showBottomSheet` method and provide it with your `Contacts` widget.

Comment: Okay thanks Amir

Comment: Happy to help. Enjoy coding 

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could run the print statement in constructor? Try this way:

```
class Contacts extends StatefulWidget {
   final String name;
   const Contacts({Key? key, required this.name}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   _ContactsState createState() => _ContactsState();
}

class _ContactsState extends State<Contacts> {

 _ContactsState () {
    print('Test2');
 }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text(widget.name));
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work